# JQuery Draggable Offset Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, draggable

I am having an issue with draggable. When you start dragging, the cursors' position is measured relative to [0,0] of the window, not the parent `<div>` of the draggable elements.

For example, if the parent container is offset by a `margin-left:200px`, when you try to drag-right an element that is sitting against the left border of the container, it will only start moving once the cursor is 200 pixel to the right of this left border.

For an actual demo please see (I couldn't replicate this on JSFiddle): [Demo](http://bangcampaign.com.au/Bang_Photo_Mod/)

I imagine this requires some modification to the draggable source. It's just a little complicated for me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could get the parents offset by using $(element).offsetParent(). Especially handy when parent elements are positioned absolute.
You could write a loop to go over all parent elements and compound their offsets.

And FYI your demo doesnt work on touch-enabled devices ;)

**Update**
I took a look at your demo, (finally on a pc again). If you remove the 'position:relative' of the div.container the draggables work as expected (or at least as I think you expect them to behave :D ).

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how I would implement this in the context of draggable though.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had made some modifications to draggable.js which were actually causing the issue from the start.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue and was able to solve it by first calculating the offset of the bounding box to the window, both left and right. Next I updated the containment x1, y1, x2, y2 positions to reflect the position of the bounding box.